# Format cell when exporting to Excel

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I want to format certain cell values when right clicking the grid and choosing Export to Excel. I assume I'm going to use the `processCellCallback` function but how do I call it or override it?

I found the export function here `this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel` but I'm not sure how to connect the two, and I can't find any good examples at the [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/).

This is what I've tried:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
    columnDefs: [{
        // Here are my column definitions
    }],
    processCellCallback: function (params) {
        console.log(params)
        if (params.column.getColId() === 'Created' && params.value) {
            return this.toDateTime(params.value);
        } else {
            return params.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `processCellCallback` and other options for exporting found on the page that you linked to, should be part of a params object that gets passed to the `exportDataAsExcel` function. Your set up should look more like this:

```
function myExcelExport () {
    function formattingFunction (params) {
        console.log(params)
        if (params.column.getColId() === 'Created' && params.value) {
            return this.toDateTime(params.value);
        } else {
            return params.value;
         }
    }
    excelParams = {
        ...
        processCellCallback: formattingFunction,
        fileName: 'export.xls',
        skipHeaders: true,
        ...
    }
    this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel(excelParams)
}
```

---

Also, if you are using the enterprise features, there is a [dedicated members forum and other resources](https://www.ag-grid.com/support.php) available to you that let you have more dedicated support.

Comment: Yes, we have enterprise so I'll be sure to check out the forums in the future. So, when do I call `myExcelExport`? I want to attach it to the context menu's "Export to Excel" button. Or do I have to create my own context menu export button, I can't use the default export button?

Comment: Also, what is `this` on the last row? I think it throws undefined right now.

Comment: @Niklas I did write this answer quickly so my scoping might be off... I was just copying what you had in your question. Also about the export button, yes you would need to [configure your own context menu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0), but it is really simple, and I could add it to the answer for your reference

Answer (score 1):

Set the callback in correct location in grid options:

```js
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
    columnDefs: [{
        // ...
    }],
    defaultExcelExportParams: {
        processCellCallback: function (params) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Ag-grid will pick it up when the default Excel export is invoked.

Comment: This along with sister option `defaultCsvExportParams` works perfectly for applying formatting when exporting with right-click context menu